# Reading JS variables in a locally stored HTML frameset

Tags: firefox, same-origin-policy, frameset

I can't read JS variables across frames in a LOCALLY stored HTML frameset

The "same origin" policy fires even when one declares a variable in a locally stored frameset (e.g. in the htm page that defines the frameset = the "parent"). When trying to access this variable from a frame, there is a "permission denied on cross-origin object" error. This happens with Firefox, while Internet Explorer has no objections.

Now this is clearly not a "cross-origin object". I think it is a bug in Firefox. It ruined an application that I wrote that we distributed on many CDRs to customers. The application relied on reading those Javascript variables across a local frameset. I wonder if there is a way to make it work again. Help would be much appreciated.

Examples: unfortunately, this only applies to locally stored files so I can't demonstrate it. You'd have to store the three files locally to see the problem.

Here are my example files online:
http://mpeters.de/temp/frameset/sameorigin_frameset.htm
But as I said, it works here in the online version.

What happens in the "parent" file:

```
<script>var parentvar='hello';</script>

<frameset>
    <frame name="frame1" src="sameorigin_frame1.htm">
    <frame name="frame2" src="sameorigin_frame2.htm">
</frameset>
```

In the "frame1" frame:

```
<script>var frame1var=parent.parentvar;alert(frame1var);</script>
```

Loading the frameset as a local file leads to an error in Firefox.

The frame should read and display the variable from the parent file. In MSIE, it does. In Firefox, I get "SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "parentvar" on cross-origin object"

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have settings to turn on / off cross-origin policy. You can try CORS Anywhere or one of the other add-ons for FireFox to allow all cross-origin traffic.

The second option is to put your files under IIS or nginx or httpd and not load them as local files if that's what you're doing.

The third is to not try and get the variable, but create a global function on the parent named something like getMyVar() that returns the variable value and call the function from the frame using parent.getMyVar().  This works in FireFox:

**parent.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>


<script>var parentvar='hello';
function getParentVal() { return parentvar; }
</script>

<frameset cols="50%,50%">
    <frameset rows="100,300">
        <frame name="frame1" src="child.html">
        <frame name="frame2" src="child.html">
    </frameset>
</frameset>


</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="background-color:red;">

<script>
var frame1var=parent.getParentVal();document.write(frame1var);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My program is distributed to many people on CDs, so options 1 and 2 are not possible. I would love option 3 to work but unfortunately, Firefox says "SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "getParentVal" on cross-origin object" (pointing to the child frame)